# How to display surfaces temporal movement

Tags: image, matlab, video, video-processing

I should display the temporal movement of two surfaces in the same video. I decreased opacity of the external surface to better visualize the internal and external surface at the same time.

When I run the video I don't see the internal surface movement. The external surface has not a good visualisation.

```
load LV.mat
for i = 1:26
   endo_v3  = ones( 3, 758, 26 );
   epi_v3   = ones( 3, 758, 26 );

   endo_v3  = endo_vertices( :, :, i );
   epi_v3   = epi_vertices(  :, :, i );

   figure(2)

   p_epi    = patch( 'Faces', epi_face, 'Vertices', epi_v3' );

   set( p_epi, 'FaceAlpha', .3, 'EdgeColor', [1 1 1], 'EdgeAlpha', 0.5 )
   set( p_epi, 'Facecolor', 'r' )

   p_endo   = patch( 'Faces', endo_face, 'Vertices', endo_v3' );

   set( p_endo,'EdgeColor',[0 0 1])
   set( p_endo,'Facecolor','b')

   axis off
   pause( .001 );
end
```

Can someone help me to have a better view of my video ?

Answer (score 1):

If you add the `LV.mat` file ( it seems some variables used in the script are or may be stored in it )
it will be possible run your script and "see" the movie.

With respect to the script, the following lines of code:

```
endo_v3 = ones( 3, 758, 26);
epi_v3  = ones( 3, 758, 26);

figure(2)

axis off
```

can be moved outside the loop.

Also, an interval of "`0.001`" seconds, seems very short.

Try also deleting the two patches at the end of each iteration by adding

```
delete( [p_epi p_endo] );
```

just after "`pause( .001 );`"

A way different approach might be to use the functions "`getframe`" and "`movie`": in the documentation page of "`getframe`" there is a useful example.

Hope this helps.